# how to find words within a range in a TreeSet<String> using regular expressions (java)

Tags: java, regex

I am iterating though a TreeSet and printing it out:

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

output:

```
after
explorers
giant
hoping
internet
into
.
.
.
virtual 
world
```

However, I would like to *only* print out those strings who's first character is within the range m-z. I have been playing around with java.util.regex, with no success:

```
String pattern = "[^m-z]";
```

Do I have the right idea here? Or is there a simpler way of doing this? All I want to do is make sure I **only print out those Strings in the TreeSet who's first character is within the range m-z.**

Answer (score 5):

First of all, your regular expression is wrong.  You want

```
"^[m-z]"
```

Second of all, you don't show the code you're using to do the matching.

Third: If you're willing to do something besides regular expressions and iteration, you should look into SortedSet.tailSet.  That's probably what your teacher wants.

Comment: It's not irrelevant. SortedSets are designed to support this sort of range quer with the sub-, head-, and tailSet methods.

Comment: @erickson, he explicitly said he's iterating through it.  He didn't ask for help with sub-, head- and tailSet.  Maybe that's what his teacher wanted, but I answered the question, not the implied question.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about regular expressions, but you can easily find those Elements that begin with a letter from m-z:

```
wordSet.tailSet("m", true);
```

Usually you would use subSet() with the lower bound and the next character from the upper bound, but since z is the last character that can't easily be done.

For getting the set from 'b' to 'y' you'd do

```
wordSet.subSet("b", true, "z", false);
```

Comment: Definitely in the spirit of TreeSet.

Comment: If you say "Elements that being with letter from m-z", shouldn't you have said '.tailSet("m"'?

Answer (score 3):

I agree this sounds suspiciously like homework, but here we go...

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
    String element = it.next();
    if (element.toLowerCase().matches("^[m-z].*")) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

seems like an homework but anyhow,
the "[^m-z]" means NOT m-z

try putting the "^" outside the "[]"

Have a look at the [Pattern](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class
and BTW, try `String.matches()`

Comment: BTW, saua answer is the best since it is way more efficient (memory and performance wise)

Answer (score 2):

I know the original poster discussed using a regular expression, but maybe he had a problem to solve, decided to use regular expressions, and now [has two problems to solve](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001016.html).

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
    String element = (String) it.next();
    char c = element.charAt(0);
    if (c >= 'm' && c <= 'z') {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

This seems to meet his requirement set out in bold in the original question, although it is possible his teacher dictated the use of regular expressions.

EDIT: I only bothered to read the full question just now. However, I still think it is valuable to understand that regular expressions aren't the only way to solve this problem.